# How would I do a search with two columns in PostgreSQL (TypeORM)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm currently taking a look at how to implement searching into my project. I have a table called users and it has two columns, firstName and lastName. I want to be able to search between these two columns, for example a user's first name would be John, last name is Smith so when they search John Smith, it would return user(s) with that name.

Or they could search just for first name etc. What would be the way to approach this?

Is utilizing PostgreSQL's full text capabilities the right path here? I'm currently using Node w/TypeORM & PostgreSQL here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that I always use in my projects.

I use conditional [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) to "build" the query dynamically. See [this](https://www.sanity.io/blog/how-to-conditionally-build-an-object-in-es6) for more information.

```js
function findUsers(firstName?: string, lastName?: string): Promise<User[]> {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);

    return userRepository.find({
      where: {
        ...(firstName !== undefined && { firstName: firstName }),
        ...(lastName !== undefined && { lastName: lastName }),
      }
    });
}
```

Note that this approach take into account the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters (case sensitive). E.g. `John !== john`.

Usage example:

```js
// Find all users
const allUsers = await findUsers(undefined, undefined); // You can remove this by checking if both parameters are undefined and throw an error

// Find all users with 'John' as first name
const allUsersJohnFirstName = await findUsers("John", undefined);

// Find all users with 'Doe' as last name
const allUsersDoeLastName = await findUsers(undefined, "Doe");

// Find all users named 'John Doe'
const allUsersJohnDoe = await findUsers("John", "Doe");
```

If you want a case insensitive use the [`ILike`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) operator:

```js
function findUsers(firstName?: string, lastName?: string): Promise<User[]> {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);

    return userRepository.find({
      where: {
        ...(firstName !== undefined && { firstName: ILike(firstName) }),
        ...(lastName !== undefined && { lastName: ILike(lastName) }),
      }
    });
}
```